# Wrong output in printing values using for loop in C

Tags: c

I wrote a simple C program to print all the multiples of 3 but there is some error during runtime my code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void) {
    int i, x;
    for(i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
        x = i % 3;
        if(x == 0) {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
     }
}
```

the problem is that if I enter numbers greater than 891 till 1000 in the loop the output is starting from 6 instead of 3 and if i write the code as above than the output is starting from 114. for the values less than or equal to 891 it is showing the correct output.

Comment: This works for me. how are you viewing the output?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, what you posted behaves properly. Try redirecting the output to a file, might be whatever you're using to view the output that's truncating it.

Comment: I am using code::blocks its running it in command prompt....Yes I guess the output is truncated

Comment: For me too its working fine.But i dont know why are you using variable x.its not necessary.We can simply use. if((i%3)==0) { printf("%d\n",i);}.In this way you can avoid use of variable x.

Comment: @Rajdhar but you will need a variable for the if statement i guess, or u saying to directly put the expression i%3 inside if?

Comment: Why not just have `i` count by 3's in the loop?  eg. `for(i=3; i<1000; i+=3)`?

Comment: this was just a piece of code from a bigger problem and its purpose is to calculate other number's multiples upto 1000 so I wrote a common for loop upto 1000 for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you can view all output:

```
reuts@reuts-K53SD:~/ccccc$ cat mmph.c && gcc mmph.c
#include<stdio.h>
main(){

    int i,x;
    for(i=1;i<1000;i++)
    {
        x=i%3;

        if(x==0){
            printf("%d\n",i);

        }
    }
}
reuts@reuts-K53SD:~/ccccc$ ./a.out | egrep "^3$|999"
3
999
```

As you can see, this works. Your output is probably truncated.